# Does this game theory dilemma exist?

Tags: game-theory

Two agents needs to prove a common knowledge by means of answering a question, without revealing the answer if the other party doesn’t know the answer.

Real world example:
Two strangers arrive at a residential building door, protected by a pin code. If one enter the code, the other sees it wether he had previous knowledge of it or not. So they must prove to each other they both know the code without revealing the answer.
If they both reveal the right answer, all good.
If they both reveal wrong answers, all good.
But if one reveals the right answer and the other don’t, one party has gained knowledge.

Has this dilemma been framed in game theory ?

Closest I could find is zero knowledge proof (ZKP) which is I assume part of it, but not exactly a dilemma.

Cheers!

Comment: This sound like an interesting problem. This would be a game of imperfect information. One component is the action space (reveal, not reveal), the other the state of the players (knows, doesn't know). It sounds like the players decide simultaneously, this is an important detail. I fear that you need to specify the preferences of the players more. As the problem is stated now, it is not clear that there is an incentive to reveal the code at all. So the dominant strategy may be to simply not reveal the code.

Comment: Not sure about a game theoretic formulation. However, for the example problem, the first party can enter one half of the pin (eg: 3 digits of a 6 digit pin) and the second party completes it. The door only opens if they got their half of the pin right. The door remains closed if either party enters incorrect digits. There is a very small probability of them getting the pin right by chance without knowing it. The protocol works without sharing the pin in full.

Comment: Don't they also give a square filled with numbers in these games?

Answer (score 0):

Start by considering the case where one person knows and the other doesn't. To prevent the other person from gaining information, the first person would have to tell a code at random. Since neither person knows the status of the other person, when both people know, they still each tell a code at random. Therefore, no matter what happens, both people tell a code at random.